# MySQL returns huge result but shouldn't

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have two tables, lets name them *table1* and *table2*.

*Table1* stores a date in plain format dd.mm.yyyy, *table2* stores a date as UNIX timestamp.

Now, I want to select some fields from *table1* where the date IS NOT the date in *table2*. I built this query:

```
SELECT 
    table1.field1,
    table1.field2,
    table1.field3,
    table1.THEDATE
FROM
    table1,
    table2
WHERE
    table1.THEDATE<> FROM_UNIXTIME(table2.THEUNIXDATE, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

To compare the two dates, I am converting the UNIX timestamp to the format in which the date from *table1* is given.

I don't know if the conversion or the comparision fails, but I get a huge result (last time I aborted the query was at 1 million rows). I think I am messing up with the cartesian product, but I can't figure out where and why.

Comment: table1 and table2 are uncorrelated. You get (part of) a Carthesian product

Comment: use a [`JOIN`](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

Comment: This has so many red flags... You need a unique identifier on each table generally its called a primary key.. Why are you storing dates in that format?? Convert the date to an actual date instead of varchar... And no n the tables together with JOIN don't do the Cartesian product

Comment: How many rows are in each table?

Comment: Is the data type of table1 THEDATE actually a date object? Or a string? Mysql doesn't store dates like that generally.. Usually its in the format yyyy-mm-dd.. If its not a date you need to convert it.. Probably why its taking so long

Comment: @JohnRuddell Yes, THEDATE is a varchar object. I got the table in this format and I now have to deal with the conversion to the other format.

Comment: @knot22 table1 consists of ~32k rows, table2 of ~64k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to select some fields from *table1* where the date IS NOT the date in *table2*

This sort of problem is generally known as an *anti-join*.  There are a number of ways that it can be resolved:

1. `NOT IN`:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   t1
   WHERE  THEDATE NOT IN (
            SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(THEUNIXDATE, '%d.%m.%Y') FROM t2
          )
   ```
2. `NOT EXISTS`:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   t1
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT *
            FROM   t2
            WHERE  t1.THEDATE = FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.THEUNIXDATE, '%d.%m.%Y')
          )
   ```
3. An outer join:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   t1 LEFT JOIN t2
             ON t1.THEDATE = FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.THEUNIXDATE, '%d.%m.%Y')
   WHERE  t2.THEUNIXDATE IS NULL
   ```

@Quassnoi has blogged about the relative performance characteristics of these three options where the correlated columns are [non-nullable](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) and [nullable](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).  In short, in most situations MySQL will optimise `NOT IN` (which I personally feel is also the most readable approach) to be as good as any other approach.

As others have noted in the comments above, you are currently performing a cartesian product (which is of no use to you); and you ought to store your temporal values in MySQL using its temporal datatypes, e.g. [`DATE` and `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) instead of integers.

Comment: Eggy if I was not on my mobile I would have already posed an answer.. Post an answer that converts table1.THEDATE to a date using str_to_date and compare to the Unix timestamp.. The op is storing THEDATE as varchar

Comment: Thank you, the NOT IN solution did it. But the query took very long, why? Because of the amount of conversions from UNIX to a varchar date?

Comment: convert to date then compare... MySQL performs better on dates

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of queries to try -

```
SELECT 
    table1.field1,
    table1.field2,
    table1.field3,
    table1.THEDATE
FROM
    table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table2
ON
    table1.THEDATE = FROM_UNIXTIME(table2.THEUNIXDATE, '%d.%m.%Y')
WHERE
    FROM_UNIXTIME(table2.THEUNIXDATE, '%d.%m.%Y') IS NULL;
```

Or -

```
SELECT 
    table1.field1,
    table1.field2,
    table1.field3,
    table1.THEDATE
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    table1.THEDATE NOT IN (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(table2.THEUNIXDATE, '%d.%m.%Y') FROM table2);
```

The number of rows returned should be less than or equal to the total number of rows in table1 for both queries above.